# Angular 4 get form value from modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am having issues to get the form value from the modal when I submit the form. The log says the addMountForm is undefined. I have provided code snippets of my html as well as component. I would appreciate your help.

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Add Mount Point</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #addMountForm="ngForm" >
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-nowrap"
               for="archiveOrigin">Archive Origin</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel id="archiveOrigin" name="archiveOrigin" placeholder="Archive Origin"/>
            </div>
         </div>

               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>

      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('Close click')">
      Close
      </button>
   </div>
</ng-template>
<div class="page pt-2">

</div>


@Component({
  selector: 'mount-point',
  templateUrl: './mountpoint.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mountpoint.component.scss']
})
export class MountPointComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('addMountForm') addMountForm : NgForm;

  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ){}




  open(content) {
      this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
         console.log("closed");
      }, (reason) => {
         console.log("dismissed" );
      });
   }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log("adding form values ");
    console.log(this.addMountForm);
}

}
```

Comment: when you submit the form does the modal popup closes or it still remains open?

Comment: What version of modal are you using? This one? https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal

Answer (score 7):

1. Use `[(ngModel)]="value"` instead of `ngModel` alone.
2. Change `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` to `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addMountForm)"`

   and in the component

   ```
   onSubmit(form: NgForm){
     console.log(form.value);
   }
   ```

Comment: I just tried that but still seeing 'undefined' for addMountForm .

Comment: Yes, I have all the required imports.

Comment: I updated my code to the following and I am able to get the form. But using this does not allow me the use the @ViewChild functionality.
`<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addMountForm)" #addMountForm="ngForm">`

Comment: Why do you want to use viewChild. Do you want the child form to get accessed by parent?

Comment: Yes thats the use case.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work like that. i'm having the same issue.

Comment: when you submit the form does the modal popup closes or it still remains open? @Inaie

Comment: You can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xmv7rnbSfvjGg6yVzdPi?p=preview) that only the change 2 is necessary (+ onSubmit).

Comment: popup is closed after submit. @KaranGarg

Answer (score 2):

Your code was correct. Just as others said you need to pass your form through onSubmit method because it is inside a template and that's why you can't access to it by @ViewChild.

```
onSubmit(form){
console.log("adding form values ");
console.log(form.value.archiveOrigin);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kjp9zi3dswcg8AsOma38?p=preview)

Also, you don't need to use banana box `[()]` for ngModel if you don't want to use binding.

I recommend you see [this](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/) comparison between template-driven and model-driven design.

Answer (score 0):

1) Import NgForm

```
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
```

2) Change your form definition to this

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addMountForm)" #addMountForm="ngForm" >
```

3) Change your component to this

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
 @Component({
  selector: 'mount-point',
  templateUrl: './mountpoint.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mountpoint.component.scss']
})
export class MountPointComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ){}

 ngOnInit(){

  }

  open(content) {
      this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
         console.log("closed");
      }, (reason) => {
         console.log("dismissed" );
      });
   }

  onSubmit(addMountForm: NgForm){
    console.log("adding form values ");
    console.log(addMountForm.value);
}

}
```

This would work and you will get an object on the console containing all the form values.